# Booting ISO with pxelinux, memdisk: Bad file number

Tags: pxe, winpe, syslinux

When trying to boot my `winpe64.iso`, I have created on my Windows 8 box, I am getting "Bad file number" error.

What does it mean?

Comment: how did you create this WinPE? With the ADK tools?

Comment: With "Deployment and imaging tools environment"

Comment: Have you used the ADK for Win8 or the ADK for Windows 8.1?

Comment: How to know? I have 8.1 and installed ADK